# Cron job to move directory with yesterday's date to another directory

Tags: command-line, bash, apache2, cron

1. I have an image upload system on my website in home1 directory which has folders in this form `2018/04/19/abc.jpg` (year/mm/dd/finename). I need to set up a cron job to copy/move folder contents of the folder from 3 days back, i.e. 16 if running on 19, 17 if running on 20, and so on, to a corresponding folder in home2.
2. Once the directory contents have been moved, I need to place an htaccess in the folder redirecting to the new directory, like this:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/new_directory/uploads/YYYY/MM/DD/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```

   Basically the year, month and date should be dynamically generated in the htaccess file, corresponding to the directory that was copied

Please assist with the cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to test this and adjust paths.  Feel free to edit this answer to suit your needs after you do.  But, it's something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
THREEDAYSAGO=$(date +%Y/%m/%d --date='3 days ago')
SRC="~/home1/"
DEST="~/home2/"

mv -f $SRC/$THREEDAYSAGO $DEST/$THREEDAYSAGO
cat << EOF >/$DEST/$THREEDAYSAGO/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/new_directory/uploads/${THREEDAYSAGO}/\$1 [R=301,L]
EOF
```

Then in your crontab (`crontab -e`):

```
# Every day at 12:00am
0 0 * * * /path/to/my/script
```